# Mixing Jquery Ajax Post To ActionResult, can I still return a new view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After a post to a ActionResult Method from JQuery ajax post, I return RedirectToACtion, but it is not redirecting. Why is this, and how can I get the redirect to fire?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably return the url to redirect to (or something so you can decide on the client the redirect url) , and make the redirect from js.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect through an AJAX Post the below code will execute the JavaScript and redirect you to the desired page.

```
return JavaScript( "window.top.location.href ='" + Url.Action("Action") + "';" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. It **DOES** redirect. And that's a pain in case you need to retrieve partial from different controller.

What browser do you use?

They may interpret 302 http status when invoking AJAX calls differently i guess.